# Jobs-Cloud Scheduler (Google Cloud) fails to run scheduled pipelines

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm here because I'm facing a problem with scheduled jobs in Google Cloud.
In Vertex AI Workbench, I created a notebook in Python 3 that creates a pipeline that trains AutoML with data from the public credit card dataset.
If I run the job at the end of its creation, everything works. However, if I schedule the job run [as described here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/run-pipeline#scheduling_a_recurring_pipeline_run_using_the) in Job Cloud Scheduler, the pipeline is enabled but the run fails.

Here is the code that I have:

```py
import os
# import sys
import google.cloud.aiplatform as aip
import kfp
# from kfp.v2.dsl import component
from google_cloud_pipeline_components import aiplatform as gcc_aip
from kfp.v2 import compiler
# from kfp.v2.google.client import AIPlatformClient

PROJECT_ID = "fraud-detection-project-329506"
REGION = "us-central1"

credential_path = r"C:\Users\...\fraud-detection-project-329506-4d16889a494a.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
      
BUCKET_NAME = "gs://..."
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "...@fraud-detection-project-329506.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

API_ENDPOINT = "{}-aiplatform.googleapis.com".format(REGION)
PIPELINE_ROOT = "{}/dataset".format(BUCKET_NAME)

aip.init(project=PROJECT_ID, staging_bucket=BUCKET_NAME)

# file names
TRAIN_FILE_NAME = "creditcard_train.csv"
TEST_FILE_NAME = "creditcard_test.csv"

# path for train and test dataset 
gcs_csv_path_train = f"{PIPELINE_ROOT}/{TRAIN_FILE_NAME}"
gcs_csv_path_test = f"{PIPELINE_ROOT}/{TEST_FILE_NAME}"

#gcs location where the output is to be written to
gcs_destination_prefix = "{}/output".format(BUCKET_NAME)

@kfp.dsl.pipeline(name="automl-tab-training-v2")
def pipeline(project: str = PROJECT_ID):
    
    # create tabular dataset
    dataset_create_op = gcc_aip.TabularDatasetCreateOp(
        project=project, display_name="creditcard", gcs_source=gcs_csv_path_train
    )
    
  
    # Training with AutoML
    training_op = gcc_aip.AutoMLTabularTrainingJobRunOp(
        project=project,
        display_name="train-automl-fraud-detection",
        optimization_prediction_type="classification",
        column_transformations=[
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "Time"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V1"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V2"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V3"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V4"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V5"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V6"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V7"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V8"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V9"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V10"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V11"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V12"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V13"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V14"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V15"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V16"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V17"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V18"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V19"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V20"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V21"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V22"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V23"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V24"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V25"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V26"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V27"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "V28"}},
            {"numeric": {"column_name": "Amount"}},
        ],
        dataset=dataset_create_op.outputs["dataset"],#dataset_with_FeatEng,
        target_column="Class",
        budget_milli_node_hours=1000,
    )
    
    # batch prediction after training
    batchprediction_op = gcc_aip.ModelBatchPredictOp(
        model=training_op.outputs["model"],
        job_display_name='prediction1',
        gcs_source=gcs_csv_path_test,
        project=project,
        machine_type="n1-standard-2",
        gcs_destination_prefix=gcs_destination_prefix,
    )
    

COMPILED_PIPELINE_PATH = r"C:\Users\...\tabular_classification_pipeline.json"
SCHEDULE = "5 5 * * *"
DISPLAY_NAME = 'fraud_detection'

# compile pipeline
compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=pipeline,
    package_path=COMPILED_PIPELINE_PATH,
)

# job run after its creation
job = aip.PipelineJob(
    display_name=DISPLAY_NAME,
    template_path=COMPILED_PIPELINE_PATH,
    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
)
job.run()

# api_client = AIPlatformClient(project_id=PROJECT_ID, region=REGION)

# schedule training/prediction every day at a certain hour
# api_client.create_schedule_from_job_spec(
#    job_spec_path=COMPILED_PIPELINE_PATH,
#    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
#    schedule=SCHEDULE,
# )
```

Looking at the error log, I found:

```
{
httpRequest: {
status: 404
}
insertId: "13yj575g2rylrz9"
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
jobName: "projects/fraud-detection-project-329506/locations/us-central1/jobs/pipeline_pipeline_179e648c_0-11-a-a-a"
status: "NOT_FOUND"
targetType: "HTTP"
url: "https://us-central1-fraud-detection-project-329506.cloudfunctions.net/templated_http_request-v1"
}
logName: "projects/fraud-detection-project-329506/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-10-19T18:00:00.309225533Z"
resource: {
labels: {
job_id: "pipeline_pipeline_179e648c_0-11-a-a-a"
location: "us-central1"
project_id: "fraud-detection-project-329506"
}
type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2021-10-19T18:00:00.309225533Z"
}
```

Does it mean that I have to create the URL before running the notebook? I have no idea how to go on.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you shared, apparently **Cloud Function** failed to create the job.

```
status: "NOT_FOUND" 
targetType: "HTTP" 
url: "https://us-central1-fraud-detection-project-329506.cloudfunctions.net/templated_http_request-v1"
```

A possible reason from the Cloud Function side could be if **Cloud Build API** is not used in your project before or it is disabled. Can you check if it is enabled and try again? If you have enabled this API recently, wait for a few minutes for the action to propagate to the systems and retry.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now in the log I have found: `status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"`, but for my gserviceaccount I enabled the following roles: Cloud Build Service Account, Cloud Scheduler Admin, Owner, Storage Object Admin. Am I missing others?

Comment: If you have not enabled the Cloud Build API please enable it and wait for a few minutes for the action to propagate to the systems and retry. since in your service account you have given the [Owner role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions) i believe no other roles are need to be added as owner manages roles and permissions for a project and all resources within the project.
If this doesn't solve your issue could you provide the logs where you have received the error i.e status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Comment: I forgot to enable the VertexAI API, now it works. Thank you again

Comment: @MarcoAbbatangelo Glad to help.